# Who is the ghost on the back of The Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification, hogwarts

On the back cover of the Bloomsbury edition of Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire is this picture:[image: gob fire back illus]

Who is the ghost?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The costume definitely reminds me of [Nearly Headless Nick.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nicholas_de_Mimsy-Porpington)

[image]

The picture on the cover definitely resembles the description of his costume on Wikia:

> He would usually sport a ruff, which would ensure his partially severed head stayed in place, as well as tights, a pair of breeches, a doublet or, occasionally, a tunic. ... He also sported a small **moustache** and **goatee**.

As for other House Ghosts, I don't remember anyone else ever been described as wearing the costume on the book cover.

Also, check the costume he wears on Harry's first day at Hogwarts.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Given the costume I would assume that it is [Sir Nicholas de Mimsy-Porpington aka Nearly Headless Nick](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/nick.html)

Answer (score 4):

### Unknown. There are no ghosts in the section of the book Giles Greenfield was illustrating.

Giles Greenfield was the illustrator of the UK Bloomsbury edition of *Goblet of Fire*. He sent a sketchbook of his early conceptual artwork to a YouTuber called The Potter Collector. Here's the video featuring the book.

The sketchbook features an early version of his rendering of the back cover.

[image: Back Cover Drawing]

[image: Back Cover Drawing 2]

It's not entirely clear what Greenfield wrote next to his drawing. But it's something like the following:

> "icicle-laden banisters"
>   the main door p353

An [article on the Harry Potter Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/edits-changes-text-gf/) allows us to track p353 to chapter 23 (The Yule Ball). There was a typo on this page which was corrected in a subsequent edition.

Around the start of the chapter we find this excerpt:

> "You know, they’re dentists, they just don’t think teeth and  magic should - look! Pigwidgeon’s back!”
>   Ron’s tiny owl was twittering madly on the top of the **icicle-laden banisters**, a scroll of parchment tied to his leg. People passing him were pointing and laughing, and a group of third-year girls paused and said, “Oh look at the weeny owl! Isn’t he *cute*?”
>   “Stupid little feathery git!” Ron hissed, hurrying up the stairs 
>   and snatching up Pigwidgeon. “You bring letters to the addressee! You don’t hang around showing off!”
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 23, The Yule Ball)*.</sub>

Clearly, this passage was only a very loose inspiration for Greenfield's final drawing. The stairs and banisters are entirely ice-free and there aren't any students about (I always assumed it was a Hogwarts staircase at night when only the ghosts are about).

The context of the original passage does at least clarify who the owl is on the back cover.

[image: Owl]

It's Pigwidgeon.

Nevertheless, it doesn't help us identify the ghost. Greenfield's initial sketch didn't feature a ghost, or a suit of armour. These are added in at a later date, so can be put down to artist licence. Here's a more finished sketch featuring the ghost.

[image: Artwork]

As for which ghost Greenfield wanted to depict, we simply can't say. It may not have been *any* particular named ghost; it could've been just a background filler ghost. Personally, I think his portly demeanour suggests the Fat Friar, but that really is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say it is the Fat Friar. I can't recall any other ghost described as "round and jolly to all." He's the Hufflepuff house ghost.

Comment: Isn't the Fat Friar described as wearing a Monk's Robe?

Answer (score -4):

I always thought it was Peeves. He’s the trouble-making ghost at Hogwarts who got cut out of the movies.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some details as to why you think this?

Comment: I always thought this way just because no other ghost fits the description of the ghost on the back, who kind of looks like a jokester. Also, on Pottermore there is a photo of peeves (up above) that looks similar to the ghost on the back of The Goblet of Fire. I hope that kind of made sense.

Comment: Peeves isn't a ghost, though. He's a poltergeist.